# is there any way to show all info windows on Maps API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

So, as in title: is there any way to show all info windows on Maps API v2?

I've read that it cannot show only one at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope.

According to the docs, only 1 info window is shown at a time.

But you can have a custom marker which looks like an info window.

> An info window allows you to display information to the user when they
>   tap on a marker on a map. By default, an info window is displayed when
>   a user taps on a marker if the marker has a title set. **Only one info
>   window is displayed at a time.** If a user clicks on another marker, the
>   current window will be hidden and the new info window will be
>   displayed.